# Permission Denial when onMessageReceived should be called

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm following this [tutorial](http://android-wear-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sync.html) and got a WearableListenerService. I just implemented the onMessageReceived method and didn't change anything else.

The entry for the service looks like this:

```
<service android:name=".WearableRemoteCommandListener"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The application element contains this meta-data element:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

But when I send a message to the wearable I get this security exception:

```
06-08 21:15:41.337      579-842/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo{net.bplaced.schlingel.wearabletest1/net.bplaced.schlingel.anmosela.WearableRemoteCommandListener} from pid=822, uid=10009 requires android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE
06-08 21:15:41.437      822-940/? W/WearableService﹕ ensureBindStarted: Permission denied connecting to net.bplaced.schlingel.anmosela.WearableRemoteCommandListener
    java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER cmp=net.bplaced.schlingel.wearabletest1/net.bplaced.schlingel.anmosela.WearableRemoteCommandListener }
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1793)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1757)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
            at com.google.android.gms.wearable.service.t.b(SourceFile:1157)
            at com.google.android.gms.wearable.service.t.a(SourceFile:1099)
            at com.google.android.gms.wearable.service.t.handleMessage(SourceFile:1077)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I tried to add the exported and enabled attribute, restarted the wearable but the exception happens again. Is there a permission missing? What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: can you get rid of this line `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"` and run it again ?

Comment: That was the problem. Now it works. You should add your comment as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get rid of this line

```
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
```

from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE)

> Must be required by an NotificationListenerService, to ensure that
>   only the system can bind to it.